# How to fix java.lang.ClassCastException?

Tags: c#, soap

Below is the portion of code from Propertyware API that is consumed.

```
public OwnerLedger appendOwnerLedgerItems(OwnerLedger ownerLedger, Owner owner) {
    object[] results = this.Invoke("appendOwnerLedgerItems", new object[] {
                ownerLedger,
                owner});
    return ((OwnerLedger)(results[0]));
}

public partial class OwnerLedger : Ledger {
}

public abstract partial class Ledger : ClientDataContainer {

private LedgerItem[] itemsField;

/// <remarks/>
[System.Xml.Serialization.SoapElementAttribute(IsNullable=true)]
public LedgerItem[] items {
    get {
        return this.itemsField;
    }
    set {
        this.itemsField = value;
    }
}
}

public abstract partial class LedgerItem : FinancialTransaction {
}

public abstract partial class OwnerLedgerItem : LedgerItem {
}

public partial class OwnerContribution : OwnerLedgerItem {

private string commentsField;

private System.Nullable<System.DateTime> dateField;

private string paymentTypeField;

private string referenceNumberField;

/// <remarks/>
[System.Xml.Serialization.SoapElementAttribute(IsNullable=true)]
public string comments {
    get {
        return this.commentsField;
    }
    set {
        this.commentsField = value;
    }
}

/// <remarks/>
[System.Xml.Serialization.SoapElementAttribute(IsNullable=true)]
public System.Nullable<System.DateTime> date {
    get {
        return this.dateField;
    }
    set {
        this.dateField = value;
    }
}

/// <remarks/>
[System.Xml.Serialization.SoapElementAttribute(IsNullable=true)]
public string paymentType {
    get {
        return this.paymentTypeField;
    }
    set {
        this.paymentTypeField = value;
    }
}

/// <remarks/>
[System.Xml.Serialization.SoapElementAttribute(IsNullable=true)]
public string referenceNumber {
    get {
        return this.referenceNumberField;
    }
    set {
        this.referenceNumberField = value;
    }
}
}
```

In the above code i need to use the "appendOwnerLedgerItems" method to create an owner contribution entry in Propertyware. For that i try to use the below logic but it fails. The error message is "java.lang.ClassCastException: [Lcom.realpage.propertyware.web.service.soap.AbstractLedgerItemDTO; cannot be cast to [Lcom.realpage.propertyware.web.service.soap.AbstractOwnerLedgerItemDTO;"

```
OwnerContribution oc = new OwnerContribution();
                oc.amount = 10;
                oc.comments = "Test Entry";
                oc.date = System.DateTime.Now;
                oc.paymentType = "Check";
                oc.referenceNumber = "12345";


Owner ow = new Owner();
      ow.ID = 12345;

LedgerItem[] li = new LedgerItem[1];
             li[0] = oc;

OwnerLedger owl = new OwnerLedger();
            owl.items = li;

OwnerLedger owl1 = client.appendOwnerLedgerItems(owl,ow); // This is where i get the cast error
```

How to solve this issue?

Comment: i think one of the object you are providing has a parent AbstractLedgerItemDTO or AbstractOwnerLedgerItemDTO, and the server expects the other way around, try to pass this: **new object[] {            owner,ownerLedger}**

Comment: @tonakai Where do you want me to pass the above mentioned code.Could you please elaborate a little more?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much about Propertyware but can you try this, basically change the order of objects passed to the invoke method:

```
public OwnerLedger appendOwnerLedgerItems(OwnerLedger ownerLedger, Owner owner) {
    object[] results = this.Invoke("appendOwnerLedgerItems", new object[] {
                owner, ownerLedger});
    return ((OwnerLedger)(results[0]));
}
```

Comment: If i do that then i get the following error "Unable to cast object of type 'Pin.com.propertyware.Owner' to type 'Pin.com.propertyware.OwnerLedger"

Comment: Is it right to modify the web service reference code because what you suggested above is the code that is in Propertyware API references.

Comment: yeah i think it is not good idea, i was just trying to figure out what to problem is :D remote debugging

Comment: Oh ok. Is there any other idea that you want me to try?

Comment: that LedgerItem array might be causing a problem, but i don't know why. try to comment it out see if it works, at least we can pinpoint the issue

Comment: Ok Thanks. I will check it and get back to you.